# R select the second element in a group

Tags: r, select

I am trying to find a more R-esque way of selecting the 2nd element (but NOT the first) element of a group in R.

I ended up: 1. creating an index `rowNumIndex`; 2. selecting and putting the first rows in a one data frame and then the first *two* rows in a separate data frame; and then 3. "reverse merging" the 2 data frames to get just the unique values from the data frame with the first two rows:

```
firsts <- ddply(df,.(group), function(x) head(x,1)) # 2 records using data below

seconds <- ddply(df,.(group), function(x) head(x,2)) # 4 records using data below

real.seconds <- seconds[!seconds$rowNumIndex %in% firsts$rowNumIndex, ] # 2 records, the second elements only
```

Here's some pretend data:

```
group     var1     rowNumIndex
A         8        1
A         9        2
A         10       3
B         11       4
B         12       5
B         13       6
B         14       7


structure(list(group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), var1 = 8:14, rowNumIndex = 1:7), .Names = c("group", 
"var1", "rowNumIndex"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

So, data frame `firsts` looks like:

```
group     var1     rowNumIndex
A         8        1
B         11       4
```

And data frame `seconds` looks like:

```
group     var1     rowNumIndex
A         8        1
A         9        2
B         11       4
B         12       5
```

And data frame `real.seconds` looks like:

```
group     var1     rowNumIndex
A         9        2
B         12       5
```

Is there a way to do this w/o resorting to, e.g., the index?  Thanks in advance for what will undoubtedly be a soul-crushingly simple and elegant solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `base` alternative, where only 'var1' is aggregated:

```
aggregate(var1 ~ group, data = df, `[`, 2)
```

...or if you wish to aggregate all columns in the data frame, you can use the ''dot notation':

```
aggregate(. ~ group, data = df, `[`, 2)
```

Comment: This solution will omit other columns though.

Comment: @carloscinelli, Thanks for your comment. I thought that 'var1' was the only variable that OP wished to aggregate...I updated the answer with an 'aggregate all' alternative.

Comment: Nice. I am not sure if he wanted all columns or not, because this is a toy example, but it's nice to have both answers!

Answer (score 6):

A solution with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

group_by(df, group) %>% slice(2)

#     group  var1 rowNumIndex
#    <fctr> <int>       <int>
# 1      A     9           2
# 2      B    12           5
```

---

Pre-`dplyr 0.3` alternative:

```
group_by(df, group)%.%filter(seq_along(var1)==2)
  group var1 rowNumIndex
1     A    9           2
2     B   12           5
```

This solution will keep all the columns of the data. If you just want the two columns (group and var), you can do this:

```
group_by(df, group)%.%summarise(var1[2])
  group var1[2]
1     A       9
2     B      12
```

A solution with `split`, `lapply` and `do.call`

```
real.seconds<-do.call("rbind", lapply(split(df, df$group), function(x) x[2,]))
```

This will give you:

```
real.seconds
  group var1 rowNumIndex
A     A    9           2
B     B   12           5
```

Or, more elegantly, with `by`:

```
real.seconds <- do.call(rbind, by(df, df$group, function(x) x[2, ]))
```

Comment: I read somewhere that if you're using `lapply` + `split`, you should look at `by`....

Comment: Ok! Updated with `by` and also with `dplyr`.

Answer (score 3):

I would use `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(df)
dt[,var1[2],by=group]
```

As I think about it, there's no reason you shouldn't be able to do this with `plyr`:

```
ddply(df, .(group), function(x) x[2,])
```

Comment: A few ways in base R too: `df[ave(as.character(df$group), df$group, FUN = seq_along) == "2", ]` and `do.call(rbind, by(df, df$group, FUN=function(x) x[2, ]))`